# How to add a metafield to Shopify product pages that displays a video?

Tags: shopify

I would like to create a way for an admin to add a different video on each product page. Such as a field that would take a YouTube embed code. Video needs to be underneath the product description (not part of the description or in place of the product image). Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google chrome you have an extension "ShopifyFD" to add metafields.

There are other apps and API (useful for bulk) that will also help you in adding metafields to product.

Once done you can use `{{ product.metafields.___.___ }}` format to call the metafield value.